# Refutation of a Nietzschanian Argument

Tags: metaphysics, argumentation, nietzsche

Soon I will have to debate about Nietzsche and I have to contradict a thesis that he supported. The thesis is: The essence of a force is to be in relationship with other forces. I think this has to do with Nietzsche's relativism but I am not sure since the thesis is very abstract.

What possible refutations have been offered for this argument?

Comment: Not sure where it is Nietzsche's texts but there are some close quotes in Deleuze's *Nietzsche and Philosophy*.  It is hard to refute as it seems mostly right when one is thinking about Newtonian physics. In Nietzche's time there was some proposals (e.g. Mach) to eliminate forces from physics as they where deemed to be rather *meta*physical.

Comment: Hi ASds, welcome to Phil.SE. Opinion-based questions are [not allowed](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) on this site. I've edited your question to better fit our format.